# MS Access: Restoring a connection after a "disk or network error"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, share, unc

I am writing a server program for our office that reads and writes to an Access database on a remote machine through a UNC connection. The development code runs in VB 2010 on my workstation.

On two occasions during development over the past few weeks, the debugger began to consistently throw a "Disk or Network Error" exception while trying to connect to the Access database file. There are many websites that address this error, but nothing I have seen that correctly identified my problem and fixed it. I finally figured out that the problem is occurring every time our IT guy updates all of the servers, including the VS that has the .MDB file. I guess the connection from my development machine gets lost and never reconnects. The solution has been to restart my development workstation.

My question is, is there a better and less drastic way to reconnect, without having to restart the machine? I only ask because I have several customized processes and services that are interrupted when I do that. I also just want to know for my own understanding.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the network connection or the `OleDbConnection` object?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's partly what I was hoping to learn. If this is a clue: using the Visual Studio Server Explorer, the same exception gets thrown if I try to refresh.

Comment: I had similar issues at work with processes and have taken to shelling a short VB.Script that re-maps a network drive to the remote machine, and checks the file is available before it runs. I'm not saying that's a solution but it drastically reduced issues, because it allowed me to handle these unexpected annoyances much better. If there is any interruption, then the error can be handled, and then the app can wait for the connection to be restored.

Comment: @Plutonix - If I had given your question a little more thought I could have had an answer, which didn't occur to me until I was in the shower this morning (where a lot of my thinking is done). Since I can reach the server's files using Windows Explorer locally, that would mean the problem is in the OleDbConnection.

Comment: From that, I also assume you are reusing the same connection over and over, just opening and closing it?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, the error tells, that the feet of Access has been kicked away.

You can't do anything to prevent this. It is exactly a *Disk or Network Error* and it is up to your network guy to solve this as Access simply can't work under this condition - could be adjusting *Quality of Service* in the switches you pass to reach the database file, but this is really beyond the topics of this forum.

If the condition is not to be improved, you will have to reconsider the setup.